# ApplicationException base class missing?

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception

From what I've learned you should always implement the ApplicationException class for your custom exceptions in .NET. I recently started developing a Windows Phone 7, but I could not find this class. 
Is there a different class I should use now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception) class instead. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception):

> If you are designing an application that needs to create its own
>   exceptions, you are advised to derive custom exceptions from the
>   [Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception) class. It was originally thought that custom exceptions
>   should derive from the ApplicationException class; however in practice
>   this has not been found to add significant value. For more
>   information, see [Best Practices for Handling Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts).